# Metasploitable 2 stuck at starting up

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, penetration-testing, penetration-tools

I have installed a metasploitable 2 VM on my virtual box penetesting lab. I used the download straight from Rapid7's website and still I am having issues. The VM is also setup using a internal network that I setup for all of the VM's to communicate. It has been stuck at starting up for the past hour. I have also tried to reinstall the VM, but still no luck. If you have any answers on how to make it run please responnd. [This is what has looked like for the past hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8ZkN.png)

Comment: You have to provide us with more information

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also, and it seemed to be due to the vmdk file being on another HD from VirtualBox. I copied it over to the C drive where virtual box was, deleted the old VM that wasn't working and started a new one with the copied vmdk.